# Generic captures

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, predicate

I'm trying to figure out why the compiler throws

`test(capture<? extends Serializable>) in Predicate cannot be applied to (Serializable)`

for `test(e.getValue().getData())` and how I could solve the issue.

The code throwing the compiler error is the following

```
private Map<Predicate<? extends Serializable>, TaggedData<? extends Serializable>> scheduledData = new HashMap<>();

public synchronized <T extends Serializable> void conditionalSend(String tag, T data, Predicate<T> condition) {
    scheduledData.put(condition, new TaggedData<T>(tag, data));
    scheduledData.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(e -> e.getKey().test(e.getValue().getData()))
                 .forEach(e -> send(e.getValue()));
}
```

My TaggedData class is defined like this

```
class TaggedData<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1469827769491692358L;

    private final String tag;
    private final T data;

    TaggedData(String tag, T data) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.data = data;
    }

    String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't usually mess around with `?` in Generics, but isn't it forbidden to have a `?` in a Generic on the right side of an assignment?  Which the `<>` operator implicitly is?

Comment: After the change I couldn't use my data in my predicate because it expected `?  super Serializable`. As I keep the types in the map synchronous myself I now switched to a list of wrapper objects for Predicate and TaggedData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine, that you pass `Integer` (which is `Serializable`) to `Predicate<String>` (which `extends Serializable`)? This is senseless.

`Predicate#test()` serves as a **consumer**, so you need to use `Predicate<? super Serializable>` instead.

Read more: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: I went with <T extends Serializable> T data, Predicate<? super T>